# How to solve "can't subset columns that don't exist"?

Tags: r, rtweet

I use this R script to track our Twitter followers, but it didn't work this time and says x Column `screen_name` doesn't exist. Could you please help to test? Thank you very much! Here is the script:

```
rm(list=ls())

########## Twitter_Account#######

#install.packages('rtweet')

library(rtweet)

#install.packages('dplyr')

library(dplyr)

#install.packages("tidyverse")

library(tidyverse)

#install.packages("writexl")

library(writexl)

twitter_data <- lookup_users(c("FAOMoscow","FAOBurundi","FAOauTogo","FAOJordan","FAOCaribbean","FAORDCongo", "FAObotswana","FAOOman","FAOPakistan","FAOinUAE","FAOCameroun",

"FAOCaboVerde","FAOSyria","FAOAfghanistan","FAOAlgerie","FAOEgypt",

"FAONamibia","FAOMali","FAOIndigenous","FAODG","FAOBurkinaFaso",

"FAONigeria","FAOTchad","FAOSenegal","FAOBolivia","FAOHaiti","FAOChile",

"FAOWestAfrica","FAOJapan","FAONiger","FAOBrussels","FAOBrasilCoop","FAOMozambique",

"FAOBrasil","FAOTanzania","FAOEthiopia","FAOVietNam","FaoAngola","FAOPacific",

"FAOAfriqueCent","FAOEcuador","FAOSierraLeone","FAOZambia","FAO_SANA","faoturkiye",

"FAOEspana","FAOWHOCodex","FAO_Colombia","FAOPhilippines","FAONicaragua","FAOLandWater",

"FAOGhana","FAORwanda","FAOPERU","FAOLiberia","FAOIran","FAOAsiaPacific","FAOEritrea",

"FAOParaguay","UN_CFS","AMISoutlook","FAOUganda","FAOMesoamerica","faosfsafrica",

"FAOBangladesh","FAOCuba","FAOArgentina","FAOMalawi","FAOSaudiArabia","FAOHonduras",

"FaoUruguay","FAOElSalvador","FAOMadagascar","FAOFFKP","FAOSIDS","FAOinNENA_EN",

"FAOInvest","FAOIndonesia","FAOSouthSudan","FAOSWALIM","faodominicana","FAOpesca",

"FAOstatistics","FAOForestry","FAOAfeeding","FAO_AgriFam","FAOawelfare","FAONewYork",

"FAOEastAfrica","FAOGuatemala","FAONorthAmerica","FAOAfrica","FAOwbf","FAOKenya",

"FAOfish","UN_FAO_GFCM","FAOcomdev","FAOCotedIvoire","FAOinNENA","FAOJobs","FAORussian",

"FAOsomalia","FAO_Venezuela","FAOAmericas","FAOclimate","ippcnews","FAOFSNForum",

"FAOLivestock","FAOCostaRica","FAOemergencies","FAOSDGs","planttreaty",

"ALCsinhambre","FAOMexico","FAO4Members","FAOeagriculture","FAOUkraine","FAOKazakhstan",

"FAOmesoamerica","FAOinPNG","FAOLebanon","FAOAIMS","FAOGuineaEcua","faodjibouti","FAOSudan",

"FAOGuinee","FAOMongolia","FAOIndia","FAOGeneva","FAOYemen","FAOScienceChief","FAOIraq","faosouthafrica",

"FAOSriLanka","FAOGuineaBissau","FAOInnovation","FAOSouthKorea","FAOADG_NENA","FAOAfricaADG","FAOAzerbaijan",

"FaoBenin","FAOBhutan","FAOCapacitacion","FAOCongo","FAOEswatini","FAOGambia","faolocust","FAOMaroc","FSCluster",

"GACSA_news","UN_YUNGA","FAOSocioEcon","FAOMauritania","FaoCf","FAOinNepal","FAOCentrafrique","FAOCambodia","FAOMoldova",

"FAO","FAOnews","FAOKnowledge","FAOenEspanol","FAOarabic","FAOenfrancais"))

total_followers<-select(twitter_data,screen_name,followers_count)

write_xlsx(total_followers,"twitter.xlsx")
```

I use this R script to track our Twitter followers, but it didn't work this time and says x Column `screen_name` doesn't exist.I would like to know how to fix the script.

Comment: Can you provide the column names of the 'twitter_data' object please?